# Understanding C++ String Concatenation

Tags: c++, string, concatenation, string-concatenation

In C++, I'm trying to understand why you don't get an error when you construct a string like this:

```
const string hello = "Hello";
const string message = hello + ", world" + "!";
```

But you do get a compile time error with this:

```
const string exclam = "!";
const string msg =  "Hello" + ", world" + exclam
```

Compile time error is:

```
main.cpp:10:33: error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [6]’ and 
‘const char [8]’ to binary ‘operator+’
```

Why is the first run fine but the second produce a compile time Error?

Comment: String literals aren't `std::string`s.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will make more sense if you write it out:

`hello + ", world" + "!";` looks like this:

```
operator+(operator+(hello, ", world"), "!");
```

While

`"Hello" + ", world" + exclam` looks like this

```
operator+(operator+("Hello" , ", world"), exclam);
```

Since there is no `operator+` that takes two `const char` arrays, the code fails.

However, there is no need for one, as you could concatenate them like the following (note I just removed the `+` sign):

```
const string msg =  "Hello" ", world" + exclam
```

Comment: Thank you, so it is kind of an order of operations thing. I kept finding that you can't do it, but not precisely why you can't.